# primefaces schedule component not working properly with seam and richfaces

Tags: jsf, jboss, seam, richfaces, primefaces

I am using the primefaces schedule p:schedule component to create a outlook like scchedule
the jsf tag is as follows

```
<p:schedule value="#{scheduleController.eventModel}"
editable="true" widgetVar="myschedule">
```

I have created the bean ScheduleController as specified [here](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/prime-showcase/ui/schedule.jsf)

but i am getting an exception when ever this component is rendered like this

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.primefaces.model.ScheduleModel cannot be cast to org.primefaces.model.ScheduleModel
```

What can be the reason for this ?
i am using jboss seam 2.2.0.GA,Jboss as 5.1.0.GA. primefaces-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have only one version (jar) of primefaces on your classpath - check your `lib` directory for other primefaces jars.

Comment: I am uisng the same jar version . Do i need to extend/implement class/interface for schedulecontroller bean ?

Comment: the primefaces jar is there in app.ear/WEB-INF/lib folder and in app.ear/lib . If i remove the jar from app.ear/lib i am getting runtimeexception caused by the file not found excetption for org.primefaces.model.ScheduleEvent ! .primefaces configuration says just add put the jar to WEB-INF lib . Which is the proper way to handle this  in Jboss AS ?

Comment: I haven't used JBoss, but try removing in from WEB-INF/lib and put it only in app.ear/lib

Comment: if i remove the jar from WEB-INF/lib , the app is not loading